# Convert mp3 file to wav? using the command line?

Tags: command-line, 17.04, mp3, convert

I have an Mp3 file i need to convert to `.wav` to be able to import it into a voice changer program.

How do I do this using the command line?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

#### Using ffmpeg - installed by default

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.wav
```

---

#### Alternative - mpg123

```
sudo apt-get install mpg123
```

Then to convert mp3 to wav (using -w option)

```
mpg123 -w output.wav input.mp3
```

Comment: Hi ,if possible could you  expand it to run on all files in a folder?

Comment: @kRazzyR: for f in ls; do ffmpeg -i $f $(basename $f).wav; done

Comment: @datakid Looks like syntax highlighter ate several symbols in your code. I've added your working solution into answer as UPD.

Comment: @datakid You should [not parse `ls` output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/20626). Instead use `for f in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "$(basename $f).wav"; done`. This also includes proper quoting and limits calling ffmpeg for mp3 files only.

Comment: How to get 32 bit floating point wav with mpg123?

Comment: You can get 32 bit float wav output by adding the flag: "--encoding f32" or "-e f32"